# not single js file loaded in woocommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

i have problem with my woocommerce..not any single js file is loaded inside my website as u can see in this address..the odd thing is all js files are loaded in my localhost but for some odd reason not loaded in real host..do you have any idea whats wrong with my setup

i used to deregister jquery and use mine using code below

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js' , false, null);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

i removed it and removed jquery file as well but nothing work.

this [address](http://dlbel.com/shop) you can check.

Comment: Probably best to stick with WP core's version of jQuery. If scripts aren't loading you should check one of two things: 1. that your theme has `wp_footer()` and 2. that you don't have a fatal error that is preventing the full page from loading. Viewing the page source, you obviously have the latter problem.

Comment: but i can't find any javascript related error in console

Comment: You have a fatal PHP error that prevents the page from loading, so the scripts are never loaded. This isn't a JS error. View the HTML source instead. Also, enable `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` and view your debug log.

Comment: thanks so much...you are life saver man :)